# Mobile Photo Uploads to S3

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

https://aws.amazon.com/articles/Mobile/3002109349624271

I want the source code of the app given in the link, however i cannot find it in https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples . any help?

Comment: Do you seen the S3TransferUtilitySample ?

Comment: Yes , but that's a little different. Also,I am unable to run that code. Whenever i try to upload an image or a file, it says Identity pool id not found Exception, although i followed all the instructions given.

Comment: The article is about sdk v1 and It has not been updated, make sure all s3 configs are right.  Bucket policies.

Comment: Can you help me with that? I am new to it and cannot understand how to do it. Thanks

Comment: See this: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2015/03/working-with-amazon-s3-part-i.html

Answer (score 0):

The article talks about AWS SDK for Android v1. The latest SDK version is v2.2.7. See [AWS Mobile SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdk/). I recommend you try [3TransferUtilitySample](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/tree/master/S3TransferUtilitySample) as suggested by Anderson. Here are a few articles that you may be interested in:

- [Introducing the Transfer Utility for the AWS SDK for Android](http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx16PLJMWD1K9ZX/Introducing-the-Transfer-Utility-for-the-AWS-SDK-for-Android)
- [AWS SDK for Android Transfer Manager to Transfer Utility Migration Guide](https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx2KF0YUQITA164/AWS-SDK-for-Android-Transfer-Manager-to-Transfer-Utility-Migration-Guide)
- [Store and Retrieve Files with Amazon S3 Transfer Utility](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/developerguide/getting-started-store-retrieve-s3-transferutility.html)

If you really need the old sample, you can find [S3_Uploader in v1 branch](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/tree/v1/S3_Uploader).

Comment: thanks :)   The code to store files in amazon s3 is something like this. if i want to store an image from my phone, what sould i write instead of MY_FILE ?
TransferObserver observer = transferUtility.upload(
  MY_BUCKET,      OBJECT_KEY,   
  MY_FILE        
);

Comment: MY_FILE is the absolute path of the file you want to upload. The TransferUtility sample has code snippet that extracts file path from URI returned by content provider.